# Why it doesn't work to pass a "center" prop value to a style-object

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components, react-props

I want to center my button, so I used a Container with align-items property as a prop. It doesn't work. If I manually set the value of align-items to center, It works. I don't understand why prop value doesn't work.

**Home.js**

```
   <CustomizedLayout>
            <Container centerAlign ={'center'} >
                   <SimpleButton>
                       Your progress  
                   </SimpleButton>
            </Container>
            
   </CustomizedLayout>
```

**Container styled-object**

```
   import styled from "styled-components";
   export const Container = styled.div `
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
       justify-content: ${({centerJustify}) => centerJustify ? 'center': 'flex-start'};
       align-items: ${(props) => props.centerAlign };  //doesn't work
       align-items: center; //it works in this way
```

Comment: Hi Andrea, it seems to work fine.  Can you reproduce the issue on codesandbox or stackblitz or similar?